# how to bind user input value in textField with propetry "text" of the link(sapui5)

Tags: input, hyperlink, textfield, sapui5

i have got an textField :

```
  var favInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField("tfFavorites",{
  value : 'Give a name to the favorite....',
  imeMode: sap.ui.core.ImeMode.Active,
 editable: true  });
```

and i have got an button :

```
 var saveFavorButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({  text : "Create new favorite" });
```

on a press on the button, i want to build a  "createNewFavorite" function which will create a link with the name of the user text input. as example :

```
var myFavorites1 = new sap.ui.commons.Link("myfav1",{
      text: "my favorite 1",
              });
```

how to create "createNewFavorite" function?   many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
saveFavorButton.attachPress(function() {
    var myFavorites1 = new sap.ui.commons.Link("myfav1",{
        text: favInput.getValue()
    });
    //now you just need to add the new control to your view
});
```

but a better way would be to create a (JSON) model which you then bind to your TextField, and which you can then grow and/or shrink to cater for more favourites to be stored

Answer (score 1):

In the properties of button, you can add a property PRESS in which you can define your function createNewFavorite as follows:

var saveFavorButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button(
{
    text : "Create new favorite",
    press : function()
    {
        var myFavorites1 = new sap.ui.commons.Link("myfav1",
        {
            text: favInput.getValue()
        });
    }
});

or else you can write "press : createNewFavorite" and you can define this function createNewFavorite in the controller.